# How to implement a physical effect in SimCity 5, that a building swings when it is being moved?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-physics, skphysicsbody

It is hard to describe in plain text, so I recorded a GIF to demonstrate.

https://public.lightpic.info/image/2B1F_582465841.gif

I am currently working on a project that requires such effect. Up to now I have finished a similar effect on iOS with SpriteKit, however unfortunately it turns out the result is not pretty satisfying.

This is my work: in my project there is an object with an irregular shape, a constant force is applied at somewhere below the gravity center of the object and its direction is downward. I have made it a rule that the object's coordinate cannot be changed by the force, so that the object will not be pulled downwards by the force. When the object is tilted, its inertance and the force result an angular momentum, which makes the object upright. Details:

[image: Force Demo]

And when the object is being manipulated, the point of action is higher than the gravity center. As a result of combination of the object's inertance and the force, an angular momentum makes the object tilted.

However nothing has proven I am right, because the result I get from SpriteKit's physics engine is that, the object turns out to be a simple pendulum. But intuition tells me I was not wrong, in fact I did not pinned the object's gravity center to the background, and what I really did is to put the object back to the original position every time physics is simulated. But the result slapped my face really hard :(. Therefore, the pendulum swings and swings, the final physical effect just sucks.

Then I worked out a temporary solution: to multiply the angular velocity by 0.95 every time physics is simulated. This solution is clearly not the ideal one, because when the rotation angle tends to be horizontal, the angular velocity is not high enough and becomes upright slowly. However there is an advance: at least the object is able to stop swinging at last.

My further solution is that the force that is applied on the object changes with the tilt level. When the object tends to be horizontal, the force tends to be big, and when the object tends to be vertical, the force tends to be small. A simple function would describe it well: F=1000N×|sin[rotation degrees]|. This helps a lot, but unfortunately the result effect does not seem to be physical at all.

Conclusion: after many days’ study, I failed to implement the effect demonstrated in the GIF, and I feel very ashamed of that. I really hope anyone with great ability would help me. Thank you for reading my long description, I really appreciate your patience.

Addition:

There is a screenshot that shows my approach to implement this effect.

[image: My implementation]

Addition 2:

I have uploaded my implementation, which is a Swift Playground file. Download it at: http://www.mediafire.com/file/qrct5sty2cyvwsy/Swing.playground.zip

PS. As my native language is not English, please forgive my poor grammar.

Comment: The axis this is swinging on is x, or thereabouts. This requires the use of a 3D scene with its 3D transforms. Can you screenshot or otherwise show me how you've setup your scene in 2D, so I can describe how to solve this problem.

Comment: @Confused yes, the axis is x. I have added a screenshot and it may be useful. Thanks a lot for answering my question.

Comment: Hey Source, that link is dead, or weird, or local, or something. There's nothing there. You can inline images into your question, just hit the image button when editing, in the styles/editing row immediately above the text box.

Comment: @Confused sorry to bring you inconvenience. I have fixed that, and can you see the images now?

Comment: Sorry, I've seen this one. What I want to see (to try help) is what you're doing, and how you're using space, 2D and 3D, so I can make a suggestion not only on how to get the feel you're looking for, but how to make it work in your space. EDIT: oops. refreshed browser, and can see your images now.

Comment: What I see is a straight down look on something that's moving in the X/Y space. I guess you want this to rotate on the X/Y axis that's at right angles to its path of travel. But that's going to be a bit tricky, if not outright impossible in SpriteKit. Can you use SceneKit to host this object in 3D space?

Comment: @Confused You guessed it right. The real effect my project requires is that, as the object is moved in X and Y axis, it rotates to a right angle. I have uploaded a Swift Playground, which demonstrate my theory. I failed to add this effect to my project, because in an SKScene, `touchesMoved()` returns a very small movement every update, which makes my object's behavior really strange. And it may be helpful to use SceneKit, but actually I am new to SpriteKit, and barely have experience in SceneKit, so I may not be able to implement this effect at last. Anyway, thanks for your help and patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A spring, a swing arm and some rust..

What you are after is a swing arm attached to a spring and a dampener that moves on a trolley.

The spring applies force to return the swing arm back to the upright position.

The dampening (in the demo it is applied at the rotation joint as friction such as found in a rusty joint) is there just to stop it oscillating forever.

Moving the mouse applies a force in the opposite direction at the top of the swing arm.

**Pendulum V Swing arm**

One of the differences between a pendulum and the spring loaded swing arm is that the frequency of the oscillation will change depending on the amount of angular momentum, minimum tension on the spring, and the position of the swing arm.

**Interactive illistration**

The illistration shows the swing arm in action, but the characteristics of the swingarm is dependent on many many factors; The height of the swing arm, the strength of the spring, the damping, the mass of the swing arm, where the spring is mounted on the arm and fixed to the moving trolley. I have added some sliders to let you see the different behaviours.

The illistration is not an answer, it is only there to illustrate the concept, you will have to implement the solution in whatever software or library you use.

Springs are very simple, with a linear relationship between spring length and force. Lookup Hook's law.

Damping in the example is just a scalar applied to the delta rotation. `dr *= 1-damping`

The forces are applied to the swing arm at a location as acceleration and force (newtons in pixel BS units). The pivot is fixed and thus any linear acceleration is lost.

Update. There were a few mistakes in the first post. I applied the spring force as acceleration rather than force, the spring could not be tensioned, and the movement of the mouse was incorrectly converted to acceleration. The differences are subtle but important. All fixed  enjoy

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = innerWidth - 40;
canvas.height = innerHeight - 40;
canvas.style.border = "1px solid black";
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
var sliderChanged = true;
function createSlider(name,val,min,max){
var div = document.createElement("div");    
div.textContent = name;
var slider = document.createElement("input");
var valSpan = document.createElement("span");    
slider.type = "range";
slider.min = min;
slider.max = max;

slider.step = (max-min)/Math.floor(canvas.width * 0.7);
slider.value = val;
valSpan.textContent = val;
slider.addEventListener("mousemove",function(){
    if(slider.value !== slider.lastValue){
        slider.lastValue = slider.value;
        valSpan.textContent = Number(slider.value).toFixed(3);
        sliderChanged = true;
     }
});
div.appendChild(slider);
div.appendChild(valSpan);
document.body.appendChild(div);
return slider;
}

var springTension = createSlider("Spring tension :",0.5,0,1);
var springStrength = createSlider("Spring strength :",5,0.1,20);
var damping = createSlider("Damping :",0.1,0.01,1.0);
var armMass = createSlider("Swing arm mass:",200,1,1000);
var armHeight = createSlider("Swing arm height:",Math.floor(canvas.height * 0.6),Math.floor(canvas.height * 0.1),Math.floor(canvas.height * 0.8));



var mouse = (function () {
function preventDefault(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
var mouse = {
    x : 0,
    y : 0,
    bounds : null,
    mouseEvents : "mousemove".split(",")
};
var m = mouse;
function mouseMove(e) {
    var t = e.type;
    m.bounds = m.element.getBoundingClientRect();
    m.x = e.pageX - m.bounds.left;
    m.y = e.pageY - m.bounds.top;
}
m.updateBounds = function () {
}
m.start = function (element) {
    m.element = element === undefined ? document : element;
    m.mouseEvents.forEach(n => {
        m.element.addEventListener(n, mouseMove);
    });
    m.updateBounds();
}
return mouse;
})();
mouse.start(canvas);

//=====================================================================================================================
// Answer start here

const springCof = 0.3;  // characteristic of the spring see Hooks law
const dampingC = 0.05;  // amount of damping as a factor of rotational speed.
const springTensionC = 0.5; // min tension on the spring ( 1 subtract the amount the spring is stretched from relaxed length)

// details of the swing arm

var pole = {};
pole.mass = 200;
pole.dr = 0;
pole.rot = 0;
pole.piviotRadius = canvas.height * 0.01;
pole.topWidth = canvas.height * 0.02
pole.centerWidth = canvas.height * 0.04
pole.baseWidth = canvas.height * 0.02
pole.x = canvas.width / 2;
pole.y = canvas.height * 0.7;
pole.height = canvas.height * 0.6; // from rotation point to top
pole.baseHeight = canvas.height * 0.1;
pole.spring = {};
pole.spring.y = canvas.height * 0.1;
pole.spring.x = 0;
pole.spring.baseY = canvas.height * 0.2;
pole.spring.baseX = 0;
pole.spring.relaxLength = Math.hypot(pole.spring.x -pole.spring.baseX, pole.spring.y - pole.spring.baseY);
pole.spring.relaxLength *= springTensionC;
pole.spring.cof = springCof;  // characteristic of the spring see Hooks law
pole.spring.damp = dampingC;  // amount of damping as a factor of rotational speed.
                      // Basicly the pivot is rusty and provides the damping.
function setPoleValues(pole){
pole.height = Number(armHeight.value);
pole.mass = Number(armMass.value);
var lookRight = Math.pow(pole.mass,1/3)/Math.pow(1000,1/3);
pole.topWidth = canvas.height * (0.001 + 0.02 * lookRight);
pole.centerWidth = canvas.height * (0.004 + 0.04 * lookRight)
pole.baseWidth = canvas.height * (0.004 + 0.02 * lookRight)
pole.spring.relaxLength = Math.hypot(pole.spring.x -pole.spring.baseX, pole.spring.y - pole.spring.baseY);
pole.spring.relaxLength *= 1-Number(springTension.value);
pole.spring.cof = Number(springStrength.value);  
pole.spring.damp = Number(damping.value);
}

// draws a spring
function drawSpring(x1,y1,x2,y2,width){
var x = x2 - x1;
var y = y2 - y1;
var dist = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);

var nx = x / dist;
var ny = y / dist;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
var step = 0.1;
for(var i = step; i < 1-step; i += step){
    for(var j = 0; j < 1; j += 0.1){
        var xx = x1 + x * (i + j * step);
        var yy = y1 + y * (i + j * step);
        xx -= Math.sin(j * Math.PI * 2) * ny * width;
        yy += Math.sin(j * Math.PI * 2) * nx * width;
        ctx.lineTo(xx,yy);
    }
}
ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);
ctx.stroke();
return dist;
}


// draws the pole and also calculates the position of the pole top
// and details about the spring
function drawPole(pole){
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx.lineWidth = 4;
ctx.lineJoin = "round";
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,pole.x,pole.y)
ctx.rotate(pole.rot)
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo( - pole.topWidth,- pole.height);
ctx.lineTo(pole.topWidth,- pole.height);
ctx.lineTo(pole.centerWidth,0);
ctx.lineTo(pole.baseWidth, pole.baseHeight);
ctx.lineTo( - pole.baseWidth, pole.baseHeight);
ctx.lineTo( - pole.centerWidth,0);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fill();
ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(  pole.spring.x,pole.spring.y,pole.piviotRadius * 0.5,0,Math.PI*2);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fill();
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(pole.x,pole.y,pole.piviotRadius,0,Math.PI*2);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fill();
ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(pole.x + pole.spring.baseX,pole.y  + pole.spring.baseY,pole.piviotRadius * 0.5,0,Math.PI*2);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fill();


var xdx = Math.cos(pole.rot);
var xdy = Math.sin(pole.rot);
var xx = pole.spring.realX = xdx * pole.spring.x - xdy * pole.spring.y;
var yy = pole.spring.realY = xdy * pole.spring.x + xdx * pole.spring.y;
pole.spring.length = Math.hypot(pole.x + xx -(pole.x + pole.spring.baseX), pole.y + yy- (pole.y + pole.spring.baseY));
pole.spring.direction = Math.atan2(pole.y + pole.spring.baseY - (pole.y + yy),pole.x + pole.spring.baseX-(pole.x + xx ))
pole.topX = pole.x + xdy * pole.height; // at 90 deg
pole.topY = pole.y - xdx * pole.height;    
   drawSpring(pole.x + xx,pole.y  + yy,pole.x + pole.spring.baseX,pole.y  + pole.spring.baseY,3);

}
// applies a force.
// As the the swing arm rotation point is fixed this only extracts the 
// angular acceleration from the force
function applyAccel(pole,x,y,ax, ay){ // x,y where the force is applied,
                                  // ax,ay the acceleration of the force
var direction = Math.atan2(ay,ax);
var toCenter = Math.atan2(pole.y - y, pole.x - x);
var pheta = toCenter - direction;
var dist = Math.hypot(x-pole.x,y-pole.y);
var force = Math.hypot(ax,ay) * pole.mass;
var Fa = Math.sin(pheta) * force; 
Fa = Fa / (pole.mass * dist);
pole.dr += Fa;// now add that to the box delta r    
}
function applyForce(pole, x, y, fx, fy){ // x,y where the force is applied, 
                                     // fx,fy the force
var direction = Math.atan2(fy,fx);
var toCenter = Math.atan2(pole.y - y, pole.x - x);
var pheta = toCenter - direction;
var dist = Math.hypot(x-pole.x,y-pole.y);
var force = Math.hypot(fx,fy) ;
var Fa = Math.sin(pheta) * force; 
Fa = Fa / (pole.mass * dist);
pole.dr += Fa;// now add that to the box delta r    
}





// for calculating the acceleration of the mouse
var lastX = 0;
var speed = {};
speed.x = 0;
speed.y = 0;
speed.lx = 0;
speed.ly = 0;




function update2(timer){
globalTime = timer;
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform
ctx.globalAlpha = 1;           // reset alpha
ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
if(sliderChanged){
    setPoleValues(pole);
    sliderChanged;
}

if(lastX == undefined){
    lastX = mouse.x;
    getPoleDetails(pole);
}
    drawPole(pole);
// move the pole
pole.x = mouse.x;
// get the acceleration of the mouse movement
speed.x = (lastX - mouse.x);
speed.y = 0;

// apply the mouse movement acceleration to the top of the pole
// Accel is the change in mouse speed
applyAccel(pole,pole.topX,pole.topY,speed.x - speed.lx, speed.y - speed.ly);

// apply the springs force (note the spring is never compressed)
applyForce(
    pole,
    pole.x + pole.spring.realX, 
    pole.y + pole.spring.realY,
    Math.cos(pole.spring.direction) * (pole.spring.length - pole.spring.relaxLength) * pole.spring.cof,
    Math.sin(pole.spring.direction) * (pole.spring.length - pole.spring.relaxLength) * pole.spring.cof
)
// add the change in rotation
pole.rot += pole.dr;
// dampen the rotation 
pole.dr *= 1-pole.spring.damp;

lastX = mouse.x
speed.lx = speed.x;
speed.ly = speed.y
if((mouse.buttonRaw & 4)!== 4){
    requestAnimationFrame(update2);
}else{
    log("done");
}
}
requestAnimationFrame(update2);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! A spring does simulate it very well!