# How to add friction to the spring so it will reduce its rate of compressing/extending?

Tags: c++, physics, game-physics

I have point **A(x1, y1)**, **B(x2, y2)**.

And 4 declared structures:

```
struct Complex
{
    float x;
    float y;
};

struct Particle
{
    struct Complex P; //Position
    struct Complex V; //Motion
    struct Complex F; //Gravitational Force
    struct Complex Fel; //Elastic force
    float m; //which I will use later
};

struct Spring
{
    float k; // k is a constant factor characteristic of the spring
    float lo; //initial length
    int a; // Spring has 2 points added to it(the actual spring), which stores the indice position for struct Particle T[MAX]
    int b;
};

struct World
{
    struct Particle T[MAX];
    struct Spring S[MAX];
    int nb; //number of particles
    int rs; //number of springs
};
```

And the compute force procedure:

```
void computeParticleForceSpring(struct World &w)
{
    for(int g=0; g<w.rs; g++)
    {
        float D = Distance(w.T[w.S[g].a].P, w.T[w.S[g].b].P); //calculate distance between 2 points
        struct Complex er1 = (w.T[w.S[g].b].P-w.T[w.S[g].a].P)*(1/D); // calculate unit vector(direction of elastic force for first particle
        w.T[w.S[g].a].Fel = er1*w.S[g].k*(D-w.S[g].lo); // calculate elastic force of first particle
        w.T[w.S[g].b].Fel = w.T[w.S[g].a].Fel*(-1); // calculate elastic force of second particle
    }
}
```

And the procedure which changes the motion of particles:

```
void update(struct World &w, float dt) //where dt is like 0.0001
{
    for(int g=0; g<w.nb; g++)
    {
        w.T[g].V = w.T[g].V + w.T[g].F + w.T[g].Fel;
        w.T[g].P = w.T[g].P + w.T[g].V*dt;
    }
}
```

My problem is that the line with the 2 points, keeps compressing and extending periodically because of the motion gained and I can't figure a way to find to stop compressing/extending of spring infinitely until it stops slowly when the distance between them is lo.

Is there a way around it, to add friction and if the spring is inert, and the points are moved, the process re-begins once more?

**SOLUTION:**

I added

> struct Complex er

to the struct Particle to remember the unit vector of a point pointing in the opposite direction to the other point.

In the computeParticleForceSpring procedure I added:

```
w.T[w.S[g].a].er = er1*(-1);// to remember the unit vector of A
w.T[w.S[g].b].er = er1;// to remember the unit vector of B
```

In the update procedure I added:

```
w.T[g].er = w.T[g].V*FRICTION;
w.T[g].V =  w.T[g].V - w.T[g].er;
```

Comment: is this a question about physics or coding?

Comment: both physics and coding

Comment: Add an additional component to the force acting on the particle which is proportional to the velocity, but in the opposite direction.

Comment: Okey, I will try it right now

Comment: You will need to divide the (total) force by the mass to get the acceleration, and you need to multiply also the acceleration by 'dt' to get the correct change in velocities.

Comment: You do not add friction to the spring, you apply it to the objects the spring acts on. That can be as simple as a scalar, or as a force acting in the opposite direction of the springs force. Here is a example of a spring that is dampened at the rotation joint  by simple scalar `deltaR *= friction`  where friction f is 0 < f < 1 http://stackoverflow.com/a/40619488/3877726

Comment: In `update`, you're adding two accelerations to a velocity (assuming that the mass is 1), which is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks Martin Bonner, your idea worked as charm on the program, you are the mvp! :)

Comment: maybe larger timesteps can do some numerical dissipation too?

Comment: no way cause these timesteps will reduce the speed of the program, and the motion will be preserved no matter what consequently spring going infinite