# How to draw a curved spring in a HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, bezier

I would like to draw a spring in a HTML5 canvas, and show if that spring is at its rest length or not.
My spring is attached to a rectangular shape to some X-Y coordinates and defined as follows:

```
function Spring(restLenght, width, numRounds){
  this.x1 = 0;
  this.y1 = 0;
  this.x2 = 0;
  this.y2 = 0;
  this.restLenght = restLenght;
  this.width = width;
  this.numRounds = numRounds;
  this.color = "green";
  this.lineWidth = 6;
}
```

The parameters are explained in the picture below:

[image]

When the spring is at its rest length, the lines shall be parallel to each other, otherwise this means the spring is stretched or compressed. Then it will be immediately clear what state the spring is.

I'm stuck now with the bezierCurveTo() Method:

Here is my Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/df3mm8kz/1/

```js
var cv = document.getElementById('cv'),
  ctx = cv.getContext('2d'),
  mouse = capture(cv),
  box = new Box(120, 80, 0, 16),
  spring = new Spring(160, 20, 2, 0.03, 0.9),
  vx = 0,
  vy = 0;
function Spring(restLenght, width, numRounds, k, f){
 this.x1 = 0;
  this.y1 = 0;
  this.x2 = 0;
  this.y2 = 0;
  this.restLenght = restLenght;
  this.width = width;
  this.numRounds = numRounds;
  this.k = k;
  this.f = f;
  this.color = "green";
  this.lineWidth = 6;
}

Spring.prototype.draw = function(ctx) {
 var sPX, sPY, cP1X, cP1Y, cP2X, cP2Y, ePX, ePY;
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
  ctx.rotate(this.rotation);
  ctx.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
  ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
  ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(this.x1, this.y1);
  // length of one spring's round
  var l = this.restLenght/(this.numRounds + 2);
  // Initial segment, from spring anchor point to the first round
  sPX = this.x1+l; sPY = this.y2;
  ctx.lineTo(sPX, sPY);
  // half width of spring's rounds
  var hw = 0.5*this.width;
  // half length of one spring's round
  var hl = 0.5*l;
  for(var i=0, n=this.numRounds; i<n; i++) {
   cP1X = sPX + hl*i; cP1Y = sPY + hw;
    cP2X = sPX + l*i; cp2Y = sPY + hw;
    ePX = sPX + l*i; ePY = sPY;
   ctx.bezierCurveTo(cP1X,cP1Y,cP2X,cp2Y,ePX,ePY);
   cP1X = sPX + hl*i; cP1Y = sPY - hw;
    cP2X = sPX + l*i; cp2Y = sPY - hw;
    ePX = sPX + l*i; ePY = sPY;
   ctx.bezierCurveTo(cP1X,cP1Y,cP2X,cp2Y,ePX,ePY);
  }
  // Final segment, from last springs round to the center of mass
  ctx.lineTo(this.x2, this.y2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
};

function Box(w, h, mx, my) {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.w = w;
  this.h = h;
  this.mx = mx;
  this.my = my;
  this.vx = 0;
  this.vy = 0;
  this.rotation = 0;
  this.color = "red";
  this.lineWidth = 1;
}

Box.prototype.draw = function(ctx) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
  ctx.rotate(this.rotation);
  ctx.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(-0.5*this.w, -0.5*this.h, this.w, this.h);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "yellow";
  ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
  ctx.arc(this.mx, 0.5*this.h-this.my, 6, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.restore();
};

window.requestAnimFrame = (
  function(callback) {
    return window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/30);
  });

(function drawFrame() {
  window.requestAnimFrame(drawFrame, cv);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cv.width, cv.height);

  var dx = box.x - mouse.x,
    dy = box.y - mouse.y,
    angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx),
    boxAngle = angle + 0.5*Math.PI,
    targetX = mouse.x + Math.cos(angle) * spring.restLenght,
    targetY = mouse.y + Math.sin(angle) * spring.restLenght;
   
  vx += (targetX - box.x) * spring.k;
  vy += (targetY - box.y) * spring.k;
  vx *= spring.f;
  vy *= spring.f;
  box.rotation = boxAngle;
  box.x += vx;
  box.y += vy;
  box.draw(ctx);
  spring.x1 = mouse.x;
  spring.y1 = mouse.y;
  spring.x2 = box.x;
  spring.y2 = box.y;
  spring.draw(ctx);
}());


function capture(element) {
  var mouse = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      event: null
    },
    body_scrollLeft = document.body.scrollLeft,
    element_scrollLeft = document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
    body_scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop,
    element_scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop,
    offsetLeft = element.offsetLeft,
    offsetTop = element.offsetTop;

  element.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    var x, y;
    if (event.pageX || event.pageY) {
      x = event.pageX;
      y = event.pageY;
    } else {
      x = event.clientX + body_scrollLeft + element_scrollLeft;
      y = event.clientY + body_scrollTop + element_scrollTop;
    }
    x -= offsetLeft;
    y -= offsetTop;
    mouse.x = x;
    mouse.y = y;
    mouse.event = event;
  }, false);

  return mouse;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="cv" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make drawing easier, use `.translate()` and `.rotate()` to move into an aligned coordinate system.

```
ctx.translate(this.x1, this.y1);
ctx.rotate(Math.atan2(this.y2 - this.y1, this.x2 - this.x1));
```

You can then draw the spring along the local x-axis, and it will appear in the correct place and rotation.

Your spacing of the segments were wrong. `hl*i` is half the distance from the spring's starting point, not the segment's starting point.

```js
var cv = document.getElementById('cv'),
  ctx = cv.getContext('2d'),
  mouse = capture(cv),
  box = new Box(120, 80, 0, 16),
  spring = new Spring(160, 50, 2, 0.03, 0.9),
  vx = 0,
  vy = 0;

function Spring(restLenght, width, numRounds, k, f) {
  this.x1 = 0;
  this.y1 = 0;
  this.x2 = 0;
  this.y2 = 0;
  this.restLenght = restLenght;
  this.width = width;
  this.numRounds = numRounds;
  this.k = k;
  this.f = f;
  this.color = "green";
  this.lineWidth = 6;
}

Spring.prototype.draw = function(ctx) {
  var sPX, sPY, cP1X, cP1Y, cP2X, cP2Y, ePX, ePY;
  ctx.save();
  ctx.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
  ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
  ctx.fillStyle = this.color;

  var vx = this.x2 - this.x1;
  var vy = this.y2 - this.y1;
  var vm = Math.sqrt(vx * vx + vy * vy);
  ctx.translate(this.x1, this.y1);
  ctx.rotate(Math.atan2(vy, vx));

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  // length of one spring's round
  var l = vm / (this.numRounds + 2);
  // Initial segment, from spring anchor point to the first round
  sPX = l;
  sPY = 0;
  ctx.lineTo(sPX, sPY);
  // half width of spring's rounds
  var hw = 0.5 * this.width;
  for (var i = 0, n = this.numRounds; i < n; i++) {
    cP1X = sPX + l * (i + 0.0);
    cP1Y = sPY + hw;
    cP2X = sPX + l * (i + 0.5);
    cp2Y = sPY + hw;
    ePX = sPX + l * (i + 0.5);
    ePY = sPY;
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(cP1X, cP1Y, cP2X, cp2Y, ePX, ePY);
    cP1X = sPX + l * (i + 0.5);
    cP1Y = sPY - hw;
    cP2X = sPX + l * (i + 1.0);
    cp2Y = sPY - hw;
    ePX = sPX + l * (i + 1.0);
    ePY = sPY;
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(cP1X, cP1Y, cP2X, cp2Y, ePX, ePY);
  }
  // Final segment, from last springs round to the center of mass
  ctx.lineTo(vm, 0);
  //ctx.closePath();
  //ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
};

function Box(w, h, mx, my) {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.w = w;
  this.h = h;
  this.mx = mx;
  this.my = my;
  this.vx = 0;
  this.vy = 0;
  this.rotation = 0;
  this.color = "red";
  this.lineWidth = 1;
}

Box.prototype.draw = function(ctx) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
  ctx.rotate(this.rotation);
  ctx.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(-0.5 * this.w, -0.5 * this.h, this.w, this.h);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "yellow";
  ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
  ctx.arc(this.mx, 0.5 * this.h - this.my, 6, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.restore();
};

window.requestAnimFrame = (
  function(callback) {
    return window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 30);
  });

(function drawFrame() {
  window.requestAnimFrame(drawFrame, cv);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cv.width, cv.height);

  var dx = box.x - mouse.x,
    dy = box.y - mouse.y,
    angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx),
    boxAngle = angle + 0.5 * Math.PI,
    targetX = mouse.x + Math.cos(angle) * spring.restLenght,
    targetY = mouse.y + Math.sin(angle) * spring.restLenght;

  vx += (targetX - box.x) * spring.k;
  vy += (targetY - box.y) * spring.k;
  vx *= spring.f;
  vy *= spring.f;
  box.rotation = boxAngle;
  box.x += vx;
  box.y += vy;
  box.draw(ctx);
  spring.x1 = mouse.x;
  spring.y1 = mouse.y;
  spring.x2 = box.x;
  spring.y2 = box.y;
  spring.draw(ctx);
}());


function capture(element) {
  var mouse = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      event: null
    },
    body_scrollLeft = document.body.scrollLeft,
    element_scrollLeft = document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
    body_scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop,
    element_scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop,
    offsetLeft = element.offsetLeft,
    offsetTop = element.offsetTop;

  element.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    var x, y;
    if (event.pageX || event.pageY) {
      x = event.pageX;
      y = event.pageY;
    } else {
      x = event.clientX + body_scrollLeft + element_scrollLeft;
      y = event.clientY + body_scrollTop + element_scrollTop;
    }
    x -= offsetLeft;
    y -= offsetTop;
    mouse.x = x;
    mouse.y = y;
    mouse.event = event;
  }, false);

  return mouse;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="cv" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: THX for adjusting my mistake! I'm a step further, now. What i try to achieve is to have some straight segments between the half circles, so it will clearly visible when the spring is at its nominal rest length, then these segments will be parallel to each other. With only the half circles is not represented clear enough, as it will just increase or decrease their radius.

Comment: Anyway, with a correct parameter setting it could be very closely resemble what i need, at the rest length the bezier curve will be exactly a half circle, otherwise it will be like a half ellipsis What is your opinion about that?

Comment: To get the curves mostly circular, you can place the control-points 2/3 length away. To get the slopes to reflect the compression, you can keep each pair of control points a fixed distance apart. See https://jsfiddle.net/kfk0qayh/ - I draw the control points in red, and curve in black.

Answer (score 6):

### Drawing a spring

Rather than use bezier curves which do not actually fit the curve of a spring (but close) I just use a simple path and use trig functions to draw each winding. the function has a start x1,y1 and end x2, y2, windings (should be an integer), width of spring, the offset (bits at ends), Dark colour, and light colour, and the stroke width (width of the wire).

The demo draws an extra highlight to give the spring a little more depth. It can easily be removed.

The code came from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40619488/3877726) that has a simpler version of the same function

```js
    function drawSpring(x1, y1, x2, y2, windings, width, offset, col1, col2, lineWidth){
        var x = x2 - x1;
        var y = y2 - y1;
        var dist = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        
        var nx = x / dist;
        var ny = y / dist;
        ctx.strokeStyle = col1
        ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
        ctx.lineJoin = "round";
        ctx.lineCap = "round";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
        x1 += nx * offset;
        y1 += ny * offset;
        x2 -= nx * offset;
        y2 -= ny * offset;
        var x = x2 - x1;
        var y = y2 - y1;
        var step = 1 / (windings);
        for(var i = 0; i <= 1-step; i += step){  // for each winding
            for(var j = 0; j < 1; j += 0.05){
                var xx = x1 + x * (i + j * step);
                var yy = y1 + y * (i + j * step);
                xx -= Math.sin(j * Math.PI * 2) * ny * width;
                yy += Math.sin(j * Math.PI * 2) * nx * width;
                ctx.lineTo(xx,yy);
            }
        }
        ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
        ctx.lineTo(x2 + nx * offset, y2 + ny * offset)
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.strokeStyle = col2
        ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth - 4;
        var step = 1 / (windings);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x1 - nx * offset, y1 - ny * offset);
        ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
        ctx.moveTo(x2, y2);
        ctx.lineTo(x2 + nx * offset, y2 + ny * offset)
        for(var i = 0; i <= 1-step; i += step){  // for each winding
            for(var j = 0.25; j <= 0.76; j += 0.05){
                var xx = x1 + x * (i + j * step);
                var yy = y1 + y * (i + j * step);
                xx -= Math.sin(j * Math.PI * 2) * ny * width;
                yy += Math.sin(j * Math.PI * 2) * nx * width;
                if(j === 0.25){
                    ctx.moveTo(xx,yy);
                
                }else{
                    ctx.lineTo(xx,yy);
                }
            }
        }
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    function display() { 
        ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // reset transform
        ctx.globalAlpha = 1; // reset alpha
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        ctx.lineWidth = 8;
        drawSpring(canvas.width / 2,10, mouse.x,mouse.y,8,100,40,"green","#0C0",15);
    }



    // Boiler plate code from here down and not part of the answer
    var w, h, cw, ch, canvas, ctx, mouse, globalTime = 0, firstRun = true;
    ;(function(){
        const RESIZE_DEBOUNCE_TIME = 100;
        var  createCanvas, resizeCanvas, setGlobals, resizeCount = 0;
        createCanvas = function () {
            var c,
            cs;
            cs = (c = document.createElement("canvas")).style;
            cs.position = "absolute";
            cs.top = cs.left = "0px";
            cs.zIndex = 1000;
            document.body.appendChild(c);
            return c;
        }
        resizeCanvas = function () {
            if (canvas === undefined) {
                canvas = createCanvas();
            }
            canvas.width = innerWidth;
            canvas.height = innerHeight;
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            if (typeof setGlobals === "function") {
                setGlobals();
            }
            if (typeof onResize === "function") {
                if(firstRun){
                    onResize();
                    firstRun = false;
                }else{
                    resizeCount += 1;
                    setTimeout(debounceResize, RESIZE_DEBOUNCE_TIME);
                }
            }
        }
        function debounceResize() {
            resizeCount -= 1;
            if (resizeCount <= 0) {
                onResize();
            }
        }
        setGlobals = function () {
            cw = (w = canvas.width) / 2;
            ch = (h = canvas.height) / 2;
        }
        mouse = (function () {
            function preventDefault(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            var mouse = {
                x : 0,
                y : 0,
                w : 0,
                alt : false,
                shift : false,
                ctrl : false,
                buttonRaw : 0,
                over : false,
                bm : [1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3],
                active : false,
                bounds : null,
                crashRecover : null,
                mouseEvents : "mousemove,mousedown,mouseup,mouseout,mouseover,mousewheel,DOMMouseScroll".split(",")
            };
            var m = mouse;
            function mouseMove(e) {
                var t = e.type;
                m.bounds = m.element.getBoundingClientRect();
                m.x = e.pageX - m.bounds.left;
                m.y = e.pageY - m.bounds.top;
                m.alt = e.altKey;
                m.shift = e.shiftKey;
                m.ctrl = e.ctrlKey;
                if (t === "mousedown") {
                    m.buttonRaw |= m.bm[e.which - 1];
                } else if (t === "mouseup") {
                    m.buttonRaw &= m.bm[e.which + 2];
                } else if (t === "mouseout") {
                    m.buttonRaw = 0;
                    m.over = false;
                } else if (t === "mouseover") {
                    m.over = true;
                } else if (t === "mousewheel") {
                    m.w = e.wheelDelta;
                } else if (t === "DOMMouseScroll") {
                    m.w = -e.detail;
                }
                if (m.callbacks) {
                    m.callbacks.forEach(c => c(e));
                }
                if ((m.buttonRaw & 2) && m.crashRecover !== null) {
                    if (typeof m.crashRecover === "function") {
                        setTimeout(m.crashRecover, 0);
                    }
                }
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            m.addCallback = function (callback) {
                if (typeof callback === "function") {
                    if (m.callbacks === undefined) {
                        m.callbacks = [callback];
                    } else {
                        m.callbacks.push(callback);
                    }
                }
            }
            m.start = function (element) {
                if (m.element !== undefined) {
                    m.removeMouse();
                }
                m.element = element === undefined ? document : element;
                m.mouseEvents.forEach(n => {
                    m.element.addEventListener(n, mouseMove);
                });
                m.element.addEventListener("contextmenu", preventDefault, false);
                m.active = true;
            }
            m.remove = function () {
                if (m.element !== undefined) {
                    m.mouseEvents.forEach(n => {
                        m.element.removeEventListener(n, mouseMove);
                    });
                    m.element.removeEventListener("contextmenu", preventDefault);
                    m.element = m.callbacks = undefined;
                    m.active = false;
                }
            }
            return mouse;
        })();

        // Clean up. Used where the IDE is on the same page.
        var done = function () {
            window.removeEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas)
            mouse.remove();
            document.body.removeChild(canvas);
            canvas = ctx = mouse = undefined;
        }


        function update(timer) { // Main update loop
            if(ctx === undefined){
                return;
            }
            globalTime = timer;
            display(); // call demo code
            if (!(mouse.buttonRaw & 2)) {
                requestAnimationFrame(update);
            } else {
                done();
            }
        }
        setTimeout(function(){
            resizeCanvas();
            mouse.start(canvas, true);
            mouse.crashRecover = done;
            window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas);
            requestAnimationFrame(update);
        },0);
    })();
    /** SimpleFullCanvasMouse.js end **/
```

Comment: Impressive drawing! But, you are right, i'm not trying to resemble a spring, i try to visualize when the spring is at its nominal rest length, so a sinus is not suitable for my needs, Anyway, its a great demo.